# Los caracteres cirílicos se ven como '?'

Tags: wordpress, utf-8

Tengo Wordpress en varios idiomas y las páginas que tengo en ruso y en chino todos los caracteres que contienen se me han cambiado por ???????

He probado en el inicio del header poner

```
<?php
 ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
?>
```

también he probado cambiar el fichero wp-config.php. Así lo he dejado

```
/** Codificación de caracteres para la base de datos. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** Cotejamiento de la base de datos. No lo modifiques si tienes dudas. */
define( 'DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci' );
```

y así lo tenía pero nada

```
/** Codificación de caracteres para la base de datos. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');

/** Cotejamiento de la base de datos. No lo modifiques si tienes dudas. */
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );
```

¿Alguien sabe qué más puedo probar?

Comment: Si. Puedes probar a cambiar la fuente. Algunos tipos de fuentes no tienen todos los caracteres

Comment: el tema es que ayer si me funcionaban y de un día para otro los dos que tienen caracteres cirílicos se han transformado en ??????, el ruso y el chino

Comment: No se exactamente que has podido cambiar (has actualizado wordpress o modificado algo?)  pero yo revisaría por si acaso lo que te he dicho

Comment: no lo he actualizado estoy intentando forzar el tema para que el SET NAME UTF8 para las querys lo meta antes de realizar las mismas pero no lo encuentro, revisado tengo un wordpress que está habilitado para todos los lenguajes, es en el momento de imprimir los datos que sacamos por las querys

Comment: creo que el problema va más por el utf8 pero más allá no puedo hacer

Comment: Que **cotejamiento** tienen la base de datos y la tabla "**posts**"? Este dato esta en PHPMyAdmin si usas Apache.

Comment: wp-config /** Codificación de caracteres para la base de datos. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** Cotejamiento de la base de datos. No lo modifiques si tienes dudas. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

la tabla post tiene utf8mb4_unicode_520

Answer (score 1):

Este error se produce porque en alguna parte tu texto Unicode se está convirtiendo a ANSI y como los caracteres Unicode que no son Latin-1 no se pueden convertir a ANSI se transforman en símbolos de interrogación.

Puedes probar a ejecutar una modificación manual de las tablas de la base de datos de Wordpress para forzar el uso a codificación UTF-8. Para ello accede al phpMyAdmin del sitio y una vez dentro de la base de datos en cuestión ejecuta el siguiente SQL:

```sql
ALTER TABLE wp_commentmeta COLLATE utf8_general_ci; 
ALTER TABLE wp_comments COLLATE utf8_general_ci; 
ALTER TABLE wp_links COLLATE utf8_general_ci; 
ALTER TABLE wp_options COLLATE utf8_general_ci; 
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta COLLATE utf8_general_ci; 
ALTER TABLE wp_posts COLLATE utf8_general_ci; 
ALTER TABLE wp_terms COLLATE utf8_general_ci; 
ALTER TABLE wp_term_relationships COLLATE utf8_general_ci; 
ALTER TABLE wp_term_taxonomy COLLATE utf8_general_ci; 
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta COLLATE utf8_general_ci; 
ALTER TABLE wp_users COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```